# Get the front most control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an old system here, that loads user controls into a type of panel, then when a user clicks on a menu item, they find the control, then they call the `BringToFront` method on the control, making it the visible user control in the panel.

I need to know how to get the current `Front` control in the panel ?

kind regards

Comment: It's either `TopMost` or `TopLevel` - can't recall exactly which one!

Comment: I think it's going to be either the first or last element in the `Controls` collection. I.e., I think `BringToFront` changes the element's position in the collection. Not 100% sure though. (If someone wants to verify this and make an answer out of it, go for it.)

Comment: The question doesn't make any sense.  If you know the "front" control then there's no point in calling BringToFront for it, it is already in front.  All the *other* ones would be candidates.  Controls are arranged by z-order in the Panel.Controls collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`GetChildIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fz293fh.aspx), this will give you the value of the z-oder of the control. So you can test this value for each child control in the current form controls collections, then:

> The control with an index value of zero is at the top of the z-order, and higher numbers are closer to the bottom.

Something like:

```
foreach (Control x in parent.Controls)
{
    if(parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(x) == 0)
    {
        //x is the front most control
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an event for when the z-order changes ?

Comment: @Captain0, i checked for such of events but i didn't find anything, the only methods that changes the z-order are `BringToFront`, `BringToBack`.

Answer (score 2):

As Joe White mentioned in a comment, `BringToFront` changes the order of the elements in the Controls collection of a container. So if you do

`container.Controls[0]`

it will give you the topmost control in that `ControlCollection`.